# Pandas Numbers entered as Text when parsed adds one decimal point and shows data type as float64

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

when I import a csv file (df=pd.read_csv('File_Name.csv')
One of the columns which has numbers entered as text to allow having Zero at the beginning of the number appear as float64 data type, so when I try to get the length of the numbers in that column by typing df['Column_Name'].astyp('str').str.len()) i get 8 character long instead of 6 digits for example the length of 123456 will appear as 8 characters long this is because when the data imported into pandas one decimal was added to the number I tried casting the text as integer ( df['Column_Name'].astype('int64') or df['Column_Name'].astype('int32')) but i got an error Also, tried casting it as pd.to_numeric(df['Column_Name']) i still see one decimal

Answer (score 0):

Glad to answer on your question. when you import a csv file, you can add dtype parameter as 'str'.

So, you can change the code as below :

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", dtype=str)
```

Hope that you get any help from my advice. Thanks.